# MS Access: Filter query to show data whose IIF truepart value is True

Tags: sql, ms-access

I wrote a query in MS Access that its purpose is to compare the time in two different fields and if those times are 0 - 20 minutes a part, another field will display Yes - otherwise that field will display No.

The query does exactly what I want it to do; however, when I run the query, I only want it to display rows whose ConnCheck value is Yes. Below is the query I created:

```
SELECT qryBusTrips.SignupName, qryBusTrips.[GO Station], qryBusTrips.Line, 
   qryBusTrips.[Line Direction], qryBusTrips.StopAbbr, qryBusTrips.StopName, 
   qryBusTrips.Time, tblSignUp.SignupName AS [GO Signup], 
   tblGoStations.Node, tblGoDepartures.DepartureTime, DateDiff("s",
   [tblGoDepartures.DepartureTime],[qryBusTrips.Time]) AS SecondsDiff, 
   IIf([SecondsDiff] Between 300 And 1200,"YES","NO") AS ConnCheck
FROM qryBusTrips, tblGoStations INNER JOIN (tblSignUp INNER JOIN 
   tblGoDepartures ON tblSignUp.SignID = tblGoDepartures.SignId) ON 
   tblGoStations.GoID = tblGoDepartures.GoID
WHERE (((qryBusTrips.Time)>#12/30/1899 12:0:0# And (qryBusTrips.Time)
   <#12/30/1899 16:0:0#));
```

I've tried writing '= YES' in the Criteria field in my ConnCheck column. But when I run the query I get an error message that says "Enter Parameter Value: SecondsDiff".

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: Do not bracket both the table and field name but each individually: `[qryBusTrips].[Time]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ConnCheck` is a string, enter the criteria

```
='YES'
```

Also, the `SecondsDiff` result column is not available in the same query for other expressions in the SELECT list (this generates the error). You must repeat the whole expression:

```
IIf(DateDiff("s",tblGoDepartures.DepartureTime,qryBusTrips.[Time]) Between 300 And 1200,
    "YES", "NO") AS ConnCheck
```

The whole query

```
SELECT
    qryBusTrips.SignupName,
    qryBusTrips.[GO Station],
    qryBusTrips.Line,
    qryBusTrips.[Line Direction],
    qryBusTrips.StopAbbr,
    qryBusTrips.StopName,
    qryBusTrips.Time,
    tblSignUp.SignupName AS [GO Signup],
    tblGoStations.Node,
    tblGoDepartures.DepartureTime,
    DateDiff("s", tblGoDepartures.DepartureTime, qryBusTrips.[Time]) AS SecondsDiff,
    IIf(DateDiff("s",tblGoDepartures.DepartureTime,qryBusTrips.[Time]) Between 300 And 1200,
        "YES","NO") AS ConnCheck
FROM
    qryBusTrips,
    tblGoStations INNER JOIN (
        tblSignUp INNER JOIN tblGoDepartures ON tblSignUp.SignID = tblGoDepartures.SignId
    ) ON tblGoStations.GoID = tblGoDepartures.GoID
WHERE
    qryBusTrips.Time > #12/30/1899 12:0:0# And
    qryBusTrips.Time < #12/30/1899 16:0:0#;
```

The query `qryBusTrips` is not joined explicitly. This creates an implicit [SQL Cross Join](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php) and therefore a [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). Is this what you want?

Comment: To be honest, what you explained is beyond my skill sets. So I don't know how to answer your question. Ultimately, I want my query to only display rows whose ConnCheck column display YES. If I follow the instructions you provided, will that garner the result I'm looking for?

Comment: 1) The criteria `'=YES'` must be replaced by `='YES'`. 2) Replace your SELECT statement with mine. 3) Test it and you will see.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was very helpful and taught me something new. Cheers.